# Can "printf" be used as a variable name?

Tags: c, scope, declaration, identifier, reserved-words

Rules for variable names in C are as follows:

1. A variable name can only have letters (both uppercase and lowercase letters), digits and underscore.
2. The first letter of a variable should be either a letter or an underscore.
3. There is no rule on how long a variable name (identifier) can be. However, you may run into problems in some compilers if the variable name is longer than 31 characters.
   (source: [https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-variables-constants])

I'm wondering about whether, theoretically, if a `single underbar(_)` or `double underbar(__)` be used as a variable? and can `printf` or `scanf` be used as a variable?

While playing with the c compiler(**Dev C++**) and **linux Ubuntu Vi**, even if I used the above as a variable name, there weren't any errors or warnings.

The code I used is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
   int scanf;
   int printf;
   int _;
   int __;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, they can be used. see:

The code:

```
~> cat demo.c
#include <stdio.h>

void show(int i) {
   printf("Just for show: %i\n", i);
}

int main(int argc, char **args) {
   int printf = 42;
   int _ = 11;
   int __ = 22;

   (void)argc;
   (void)args;

   show(printf);
   show(_);
   show(__);

   return 0;
}
```

The compiling process with no errors:

```
~>  gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o demo demo.c
```

The output:

```
~>  ./demo
Just for show: 42
Just for show: 11
Just for show: 22
```

Comment: It might be useful to explain _why_ they can be used. Also the `__` example is not compliant.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize printf as a variable name, you can no longer use printf command same goes with scanf. Initially printf command was pointing to the code to take input but now you have assigned it to the integer.

Comment: you cannot in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You *can*, that doesn't mean you *should*.

Yes, `_` and `__` are valid identifiers in the sense that they satisfy the rules for identifiers.  They can result in code that's hard to read and may collide with a name already in use by the implementation, so you shouldn't use them on their own this way.

As for using `printf` and `scanf` as variable names, you can only do that if you don't already have them declared as functions - **In other words**, you can't do it if you've already included `stdio.h`.

C has four *name spaces* for identifiers (or, more properly, four classes of name spaces); you can only use the same identifier for two different things in the same scope if they belong to different name spaces.  The name spaces are:

- All labels (disambiguated by the `goto` keyword or a trailing ':');
- All tag names (disambiguated by the `struct`, `enum`, or `union` keywords);
- `struct` and `union` member names (disambiguated by the `.` or `->` operators; identifiers can be used in multiple `struct` and `union` types)
- All other names (variable names, function names, enumeration constants, etc.)

If you've included `stdio.h`, then `printf` and `scanf` have already been declared as function names, so you can't also use them as variable names in that scope since function names and variable names belong to the same name space.  You could, however, use them as tag names, member names, or labels, although I would strongly recommend you not do that.

Comment: Re “you can only do that if you don't already have them declared as functions”: Identifiers in inner scopes can hide identifiers in outer scopes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use names `scanf` and `printf` in a block scope or in the name space of tags of structures, unions, or enumerations or in the name space of members of structures and unions or in a function prototype scope.

A name like `scanf` or `printf` declared in a block scope will hide the corresponding function name declared in the file scope. But you may not redeclare these names in the file scope.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int printf = 10;

    {
        int *scanf = &printf;
        extern int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
    
        printf( "printf = %d\n", *scanf );
    }       
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
printf = 10
```

And Here is another demonstrative program that shows other ways of using the name `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct printf
{
    int printf;
};

void f( int printf );

void f( int x )
{
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct printf printf = { .printf = 10 };
    
    f( printf.printf );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 10
```

Naturally such using of the name printf will only confuse readers of the code.

As for the names that start with an underscore then according to the C Standard (7.1.3 Reserved identifiers)

> 1 Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its
> associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers
> listed in its associated future library directions subclause and
> identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as
> file scope identifiers.
>
> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an
> uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any
> use.

So you may not use an identifier like in this declaration neither in a file scope nor in a block scope

```
int __;
```

The name is reserved by the implementation.

As for this declaration in your code snippet

```
 int _;
```

then as it has no file scope (it has a block scope) then used in the declaration the identifier (the declaration using this identifier) is valid.

But if you will declare the name in a file scope like

```
 int _;

 int main( vpid )
 {
     //...
 }
```

then such a declaration of the identifier will be invalid.

Also you may not use such identifier as a tag name in a file scope. For example

```
struct _
{
    int x;
};

int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved
> for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag
> name spaces.

Answer (score -1):

- > The first letter of a variable should be either a letter or an underscore.

  Using underscore is bad practice since such names might collide with internals in compiler library headers. The C standard 7.1.3 states:

  > All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
- > There is no rule on how long a variable name (identifier) can be

  Incorrect, there are limits listed about how many letters that the compiler keeps track of. In this current standard this is 31 letters for external identifiers and 63 for internal identifiers. In the older versions of C called C90, these limits were just 6 letters for external identifiers, which was pure madness. If you are prone to use outdated compilers, you need to be very careful. (Dev C++ is outdated but somewhat safe in this case.)

> and can printf or scanf be used as a variable?

In theory you can do so at local scope. 7.1.3 states further:

> Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.

Meaning you can't declare a variable or function called `printf` at file scope, but you can do so at local scope. Now of course, people do declare macros called `printf` all the time for the purpose of "function mocking", so in practice it's harmless.

But the general rule of thumb is: if you do really strange things then expect really strange results. C is known to use karma extensively, to bring trouble down on those who deserve it for writing obscure code.